# Removing extra character while using lstrip in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, strip

I have a dataframe with a column as below

Input:

```
  CD

  Component Description_CAP YO
  Component Description_CAPE IO
  Component Description_CLOSE SO
  Component Description_CAT TO
  Component Description_CAPP TTO
  Component Description_CLOSE IUO
```

I have used lstrip, in which the "C" after Component_Description is getting deleted which wrong

```
      df['CD'] = df['CD'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('Component Description_'))
```

Expected Result:

```
  CD

  CAP YO
  CLOSE SO
  CAT TO
  CAPP TTO
  CLOSE IUO
```

Actual Result I am getting

```
       CD

       AP YO
       LOSE SO
       AT TO
       APP TTO
       LOSE IU
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in your solution if use `lstrip` it remove all letters defined in string from left side.

Solution is use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with `^` for start ot strings in regex:

```
df['CD'] = df['CD'].str.replace(r'^Component Description_', '')
print (df)
          CD
0     CAP YO
1    CAPE IO
2   CLOSE SO
3     CAT TO
4   CAPP TTO
5  CLOSE IUO
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.extract`

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"CD": ['Component Description_CAP YO', 'Component Description_CAPE IO', 'Component Description_CLOSE SO', 'Component Description_CAT TO', 'Component Description_CAPP TTO', 'Component Description_CLOSE IUO']})
df["CD"] = df["CD"].str.extract(r"_(.*)$")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
          CD
0     CAP YO
1    CAPE IO
2   CLOSE SO
3     CAT TO
4   CAPP TTO
5  CLOSE IUO
```

Comment: Thanks, this works too. But there's a warning message, hence going with below solution